# Is there an explicit solution to this equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, generating-functions, matrix-equations, functional-equations

I am reading a paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212823) where the author presents the equation

(1) $\pi_r(z)$=$\psi_r(z)[ \sum_{s=0}^{2N} a_{rs}\pi_s(z) ]$
$,r=0,1,2,.....,2N$

where

$a_{rs}$= $\binom{2N}{s}((1/2)(r/N))^s(1-(1/2)(r/N))^{2N-s}$

i.e, a chain binomial model, and

$\psi_r(z)$=$F(-r,-2N+r,-N+1/2,(1/2)(1-z))$

i.e, a hypergeometric function.

The author only presents a solution in matrix form and numerically, but does not give explicit expressions for the $\pi_r(z)$'s. Is there an explicit expression for the  $\pi_r(z)$'s, or no?

Comment: Can you link the paper, or at least explain the derivation of the explicit formula for $\psi_r$? I imagine, if there is such a form for $\pi_r$, the derivation may draw from the derivation for $\psi_r$.

Comment: Here's the link to the paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212823